# ASPxGridView LoadingPanel Width is too long

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

With a confliction between some class of my CSS file and devexpress's own style, LoadingPanel pop ups appearing very long (aproximately 1000px width).

This problem occures every loading popup panels of DevExpress tools, is not one of the individual controls problem..

I don't want to track and change CSS file, because it's so cool and very long file.

Comment: Not sure what you think the solution could be other than editing your CSS file or the DevExpress CSS file. This also isn't a programming issue, it's a design/layout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [ASPxGridView.Styles.LoadingPanel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesLoadingPanelStyleMembersTopicAll) properties. Use it like this:

```xml
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ...>  
    <Styles>
        <LoadingPanel ...></LoadingPanel>
    </Styles>
</dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, i found the real problem (is IE9 compatibility :@) after a lot of hours i blow up my mind.. (if anyone haunt same mistake, the solution is: define new css style class on css file, and set LoadingPanelSettings -> CssClass to it. But the KEYPOINT IS: set "min-width" and "max-width" css properties)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have overridden base CSS class/rule for LoadingPanel visual element (common for several controls).

Specify an individual loading panel appearance for different DX ASP.NET controls (as Filip suggest for the ASPxGridView).

Comment: I'm so sorry, i found the real problem (is IE9 compatibility :@) after a lot of hours i blow up my mind.. (if anyone haunt same mistake, the solution is: define new css style class on css file, and set LoadingPanelSettings -> CssClass to it. But the KEYPOINT IS: set "min-width" and "max-width" css properties)